# How to get Monaco Editor array of lines

Tags: monaco-editor

How to get Monaco Editor array of lines?
I'm going through the doc and see how to get the string value, but need to loop through each line and map the values.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```js
//  let editor1 = monaco.editor.create( ... 
let model = editor1.getModel();
for (let i = 0; i < model.getLineCount(); i++) {
    let line = model.getLineContent(i);
    // do something
}
```